# USPTO Customer Number

Tags: uspto

I submitted a customer number request form per [this](https://www.uspto.gov/patents-application-process/applying-online/getting-started-new-users) page.  How long does it generally take for the USPTO to fulfill the request and email a customer number?

And after a customer number has been assigned, how long does it generally take to issue a digital certificate?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Did you by any chance receive an answer or better now have the experience of how long it takes yourself? Did they send the customer number via email or good old fashioned letter? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I applied by fax on a Wednesday and received email confirmation of the new customer number on the Friday. So, 2-3 business days.

I haven't taken the next step, so I can't answer your second question yet.